# Can I make my iPhone to show name and number on incoming calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, phone.app

When I recieve a call it only shows the name of the contact. Is it possible to shows the number as well?

The [same applies when I call a contact, it only shows the name](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83098/how-can-i-see-the-phone-number-dialed-after-i-initiate-a-call), but I'll watch that thread for options on outgoing mods or apps.

The reason this is important to see is that I have 2-3 numbers for many contacts and it is very important for me to know at a glance if they are calling from work or home or mobile.

My phone is jailbroken, so don't feel tied to the stock iOS if a good solution exists in a jailbroken app or modification to the OS. Clearly a non-jaibreak solution would help the most people, so I'd prefer that if possible.

Comment: I will probably put a bounty on this as I did [on the linked question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83098/how-can-i-see-the-phone-number-dialed-after-i-initiate-a-call). Could you let me know if your question is totally the same as the linked one?