# Add new number to existing iPhone contact, replace the old number

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

Today a friend called me from their new cell phone number. After the call, I added the phone number to their existing contact. Afterwards, I could not determine which of the two phone numbers listed was the current number that they had called me from.

If I navigate to "Recents" and click on the call, it lists both phone numbers and gives me no indication which was used for that specific call.

**What is the easiest way to determine which phone number was last used with a specific contact?**

**When someone calls me from a new phone number, what is the easiest way to overwrite their old phone number with the new one?**

I'm using iOS 8.3 on an iPhone 5

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83098/how-can-i-see-the-phone-number-dialed-after-i-initiate-a-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blue number (the bottom one in your screen capture) is the one which made the call. The same works for emails in contacts that have more than one.

Here for example, I have a contact with a landline (home) and a mobile phone.
Incoming and outgoing calls to the different numbers of the contact are highlighted in blue.

This is a screenshot of a call made to the mobile number of the contact (not an iPhone, its my grandma):

[image: incoming and outgoing call to the mobile number of a contact highlighted in blue.]

This is a screenshot of a call made to the landline:

[image: outgoing call to landline highlighted in blue on the info page]

Also, if you missed the call, the number calling will turn red instead of blue.

This is a screenshot of a missed call from the landline:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? I thought the blue text indicated that the number was linked to an iPhone. Is there a source for this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I added screenshots to illustrate. I have not yet found documentation describing this UI behaviour.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of the blue bubbles on messages signaling that the text was sent as an iMessage?

Comment: Using my "Recents" list I can confirm this behavior. I received a call yesterday from a business landline (not iPhone) and the number is blue.  I also found another incoming listed from a mobile that is not an iPhone, and its listing is blue.

Comment: I thought the contact listing worked in a similar manner to messaging—blue to indicate iMessage capability. Thanks for the thorough answer and screenshots, very clear!